# KiwiTCMS - MySQL DB with mysql_native_password encryption method

Tags: kiwi-tcms

Setup

- kiwi - latest
- mysql -latest (v8.0.21)
- os - mac

I have change the `docker-compose.yml` as below, and it can start-up the two containers.

```yml
    services:
        db:
            container_name: kiwi_db
            image: mysql:latest
            volumes:
                - db_data:/var/lib/kiwi_mysql/data
                # workaround for missing charset & collation support
                # https://github.com/sclorg/mariadb-container/pull/125
                - ./99-charset.sh:/usr/share/container-scripts/mysql/init/99-charset.sh:Z
                - ./99-charset.cnf:/usr/share/container-scripts/mysql/cnf/99-charset.cnf:Z
            restart: always
            environment:
                MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: kiwi-1s-aw3s0m3
                MYSQL_DATABASE: kiwi
                MYSQL_USER: kiwi
                MYSQL_PASSWORD: kiwi
                MYSQL_CHARSET: utf8mb4
                MYSQL_COLLATION: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    
        web:
            container_name: kiwi_web
            depends_on:
                - db
            restart: always
            image: kiwitcms/kiwi:latest
            ports:
                - 9001:8080
                - 9443:8443
            volumes:
                - uploads:/Kiwi/uploads:Z
            environment:
                KIWI_DB_HOST: db
                KIWI_DB_PORT: 3306
                KIWI_DB_NAME: kiwi
                KIWI_DB_USER: kiwi
                KIWI_DB_PASSWORD: kiwi
                KIWI_DONT_ENFORCE_HTTPS: "true"
            links:
                - db
    
    volumes:
        db_data:
        uploads:
```

When I execute `docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py migrate`, it will get some error message.

I am trying to change the encryption method of user password from `caching_ sha2_ Password` to `mysql_native_password`, but it still pop up the same error message.

Traceback of the error:

```python
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
        self.connect()
      File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 197, in connect
        self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
      File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 233, in get_new_connection
        return Database.connect(**conn_params)
      File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 130, in Connect
        return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 185, in __init__
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
    MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2059, 'Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded: lib64/mariadb/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory')
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```python
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/Kiwi/manage.py", line 12, in <module>
       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
     File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
       utility.execute()
     File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
     File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
     File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 366, in execute
       self.check()
     File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 395, in check
       include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
     File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 63, in _run_checks
       issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])
     File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
       new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
     File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/database.py", line 10, in check_database_backends
       issues.extend(conn.validation.check(**kwargs))
     File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 9, in check
       issues.extend(self._check_sql_mode(**kwargs))
     File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 13, in _check_sql_mode
       with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
     File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
       return func(*args, **kwargs)
     File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 260, in cursor
       return self._cursor()
     File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 236, in _cursor
       self.ensure_connection()
     File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
       return func(*args, **kwargs)
     File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
       self.connect()
     File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
       raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
     File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
       self.connect()
     File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
       return func(*args, **kwargs)
     File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 197, in connect
       self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
     File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
       return func(*args, **kwargs)
     File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 233, in get_new_connection
       return Database.connect(**conn_params)
     File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 130, in Connect
       return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
     File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 185, in __init__
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
   django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2059, 'Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded: lib64/mariadb/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the official MySQL docker images with a docker-compose.yml configuration for the CentOS MariaDB image which Kiwi TCMS uses by default.

A quick look at MySQL's container image at https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql tells me it doesn't support some of the environment variables used in the MariaDB image.

The error which I see is caused by trying to use the mariadb client library (to make the connection) which seems incompatible with MySQL. And I think there are quite a few incompatibilities between MariaDB and MySQL latest versions these days.

So you need to do 2 things:

1. Figure out how to properly configure the MySQL container via environment variables as per their documentation
2. Figure out if the MariaDB client libraries will work with a MySQL server (or not).

Also see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/databases/#mariadb-notes for references.

For 2) you can open an issue on GitHub so we don't forget to add it to our test suite. IDK at the top of my head what is the state of mysql/mariadb libraries lately and if they can be installed and used side-by-side or if they will conflict with each other.

Comment: Thanks  a lot. I have find out the reason I miss a configration in docker-compose.yml.  It must be add command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password in docker-compse.yml,and then it can work perfectly